# How can I know how many characters I use with Azure Cognitive Services Speech Synthesis (TTS)?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, speech-synthesis

I use Azure Cognitive Services Speech Synthesis free. How can I know how many characters I use to be able to estimate the cost of my project?
With a free account I can use 0.5 million characters of a Neural voice for free per month. I want to know in my experiments how many characters I use on this moment.

Comment: The average word length is 4.7 characters. Round it up to 5 to give yourself some room for error. 

the Average person speaks 150 words per minute. 

So you use about 750 characters per minute of speech.  You can figure out the rest of the estimations yourself.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. Is there a way to see this in the azure portal?

Comment: (mid-2022) I still can't find "character count" among the available Azure "metrics" or anywhere else on my Azure portal. Just in case we're overlooking something [I asked the question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/934652/how-do-i-see-how-many-tts-characters-i-have-used-d.html) today on the Microsoft Docs Q&A site—no replies so far.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you are looking to identify the Number of characters that has been consumed by service at that point of time.

Unfortunately, AFAIK there is no metric to track that from the  Azure Portal. However, you can maintain the count locally at your end or the central location where you can query yourself --- add an additional logic to maintain the metrics in your code.

The character is counted based on the below conditions (that can be found [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/text-to-speech.md)):

- Text passed to the text-to-speech service in the SSML body of the
  request
- All markup within the text field of the request body in the SSML format, except for `<speak>` and `<voice>` tags
- Letters, punctuation, spaces, tabs, markup, and all white-space characters
- Every code point defined in Unicode

Exception for Chinese, Japanese, and Korean language -- character is counted as two characters for billing.

Comment: Strange, you would expect it to be possible to measure this in the protal metrics. That way I could calculate the costs.What is the best way in javascript / php to do this?

Comment: A small correction for the exception. Only Chinese characters are counted as two characters for billing. Japanese and Korean do not only have kanji/hanja(Chinese characters) in their language. Japanese also uses kana and Korean also uses hangul which should be counted as one character.